# Stuck on what seems like a simple SQL dense_rank task

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank, dense-rank

Been stuck on this issue and could really use a suggestion or help.

What I have in a table is basic user flow on a website. For every Session ID, there's a page visited from start (lands on homepage) to finish (purchase). This has been ordered by timestamp to get a count of pages visited during this process. This 'page count' has also been partitioned by Session ID to go back to 1 every time the ID changes.

What I need to do now is assign a step count (highlighted is what I'm trying to achieve). This should assign a similar count but doesn't continue counting at duplicate steps (ie, someone visited multiple product pages - it's multiple pages but still only one 'product view' step.

You'd think this would be done using a dense rank, partitioned by session id - but that's where I get stuck. You can't order on page count because that'll assign a unique number to each step count. You can't order by Step because that orders it alphabetically.

What could I do to achieve this?

Screenshot of desired outcome:

[image: screenshot of desired outcome]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use lag to see if two values are the same then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_cs = custom_step then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by session_id order by timestamp) as steps_count
from (select t.*,
             lag(custom_step) over (partition by session_id order by timestamp) as prev_cs
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), 
  COUNTIF(IFNULL(flag, TRUE)) OVER(PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS steps_count
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    custom_step != LAG(custom_step) OVER(PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY timestamp
```